# How can I send category data to google sheets without an error?

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, plaid

I am working on sending credit card statement data to google sheets using Plaid & sheets APIs.

I am able to send account, vendor name, date, and amount, but can't seem to get the categories to populate in the google sheet as well.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
{"range":"A1:E1","values":[["creditcard","Peet\'s Coffee & Tea","2019-04-01",-2.3,["Food and Drink","Restaurants","Coffee Shop"]]]},
```

---

I have tried both of the below options.

DOESN'T WORK (error message)

```
values: [Object.values(transaction)]
```

AND

```
values: [[transaction.account, transaction.name, transaction.date, transaction.amount, transaction.category ]]
```

WORKS (omits category in gsheets)

```
values: [[transaction.account, transaction.name, transaction.date, transaction.amount]]
```

---

***FETCH***

```
return rawTransactions.reduce((all, { account, transactions }) => {
    return all.concat(transactions.map(({ name, date, amount, category }) => ({
      account,
      name,
      date,
      amount: -amount,
      category
    })))
  }, [])
}
```

***TRANSFORM***

```
const updates = transactions.map(function(transaction, i) {
    return {
      range: `A${i + 2}:E${i + 2}`,
      values: [[transaction.account, transaction.name, transaction.date, transaction.amount, transaction.category ]]

    }
  });

  updates.push({
      range: `A1:E1`,
      values: [['Account', 'Name', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Category' ]]
  })
```

---

I expect all of the data in 'values' to be sent to the google sheet, but I get the below error message.

```
data: { error: [Object] } },
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { message:
        'Invalid data[0]: Invalid values[1][4]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "Service"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "Advertising and Marketing"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "Online Advertising"\n  }\n}\n',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the script for calling Sheets API?